# Using profiles to exclude WAR modules from 'mvn install'

Tags: maven, maven-profiles, maven-install-plugin

My parent `pom` defines 7 modules, 5 of which are dependency `jar`s, and two are `war`s that depend on those jars.

**Question**: Is it possible to use maven `profiles` (or another solution) to define which modules are included when `mvn install` is run against the parent pom to exclude the two war packages?

I would then like to have a different profile (or another solution) to package the two wars. If that profile is run, the dependency jar modules should be rebuilt and installed only if they are missing from the repository.

Comment: Have you ever considered `mvn --projects Module --also-make-dependent`?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `build-helper-maven-plugin` in your parent `pom.xml` file to create a new property based on the `packaging` (at runtime it would change from `pom` for the parent, to `jar` and `war` for the modules). This new propery could then be used to skip the `maven-install-plugin` dynamically.

A simple example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.10</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-helper-regex-is-packaging-war</id>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>regex-property</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>only.when.war.is.used</name>
                <value>${project.packaging}</value>
                <regex>war</regex>
                <replacement>true</replacement>
                <failIfNoMatch>false</failIfNoMatch>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${only.when.war.is.used}</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Doing so, the dynamic `${only.when.war.is.used}` property would be set to `true` only when `project.packaging` would have value `war` and as such effectively skip the `maven-install-plugin` executions via its `skip` option.

---

You could then move this behavior to a profile and have different settings for `jar` and `war`, keeping them in a common place: the root `pom.xml`, thanks to their dynamic behavior.

---

Concerning the ability to detect whether an artifact has already been installed or not, there is no such an option on the [official](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) plugin documentation and I don't think you could have such a behavior by simply using the plugin.

You could however use the [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) activation mechanism in case a file is missing (the installed file) and activate the profile accordingly.

You could have in a dynamic way (based only on standard properties) the following approach:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <activation>
      <file>
        <missing>${settings.localRepository}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.build.fileName}.${project.packaging}</missing>
      </file>
    </activation>
    ...
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: @amphibient did you solve this issue? did the answer help you out?